# How to parse the text file and return url using multiprocessing

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing

I have a text file. I need to load data from a file using the URLExtract module, parse messages_to_parse and extract all URLs from there (multiprocessing)
Check each of these addresses for availability using
requests.head (multithreading).
At the output, form a dictionary in which the key is url, and the value is its status code, which returned requests.head request I would be grateful for any help, please, could you correct my code?

```
import concurrent.futures
import pickle
import requests
import time
from urlextract import URLExtract

out = []
CONNECTIONS = 100
TIMEOUT = 5

with open('messages_to_parse.dat', 'rb') as f:
   tlds = str(pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1'))
extractor = URLExtract()
urls = [url for url in extractor.gen_urls(tlds)]


def load_url(url, timeout):
   ans = requests.head(url, timeout=timeout)
   return ans.status_code


print(load_url(urls, 5))

with 
 concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=CONNECTIONS) 
  as executor:
    future_to_url = (executor.submit(load_url, url, TIMEOUT) for 
url in urls)
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
    try:
        data = future.result()
    except Exception as exc:
        data = str(type(exc))
    finally:
        out.append(data)

        print(str(len(out)), end="\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have it now, `tlds` is a single string and you cannot apply multiprocessing to process this using the `UrlExtract.gen_urls` method. If, however, the result of the `pickle.load` function is actually a list of individuals strings as the name `tlds` suggests, which you are converting into a single string with the `str` function, then if you keep it as an actual list, you can use multiprocessing to process each string in parallel (although it may not save you any computing time depending on how CPU-intensive the computation is). Based on the assumption that `pickle.load` returns a list of strings, I offer the following possible solution and a few notes:

1. If you are going to break up a long Python statement across multiple lines, then you need to continue the statement to the next line by adding a `\` character at the end of the line.
2. There is no need to create a thread pool greater than the size of the `urls` list if `len(urls) < CONNECTIONS`.
3. Variable name `future_to_url` suggests that this is a mapping from a future to a URL so that given a future you can recover the URL for which this future was created. This would require that this variable be a dictionary.
4. Your `as_completed` loop should be within the `with ... as executor:` block. Having it after the block means it will not execute until after the implicit call to `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` has been made and therefore all the pending futures are done executing, which defeats the whole purpose of using `as_completed`.

The code:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor, \
                               as_completed
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import pickle
import requests
import time
from urlextract import URLExtract

CONNECTIONS = 100
TIMEOUT = 5

def load_url(url, timeout):
    ans = requests.head(url, timeout=timeout)
    return ans.status_code

def extract_urls(text):
    extractor = URLExtract()
    return extractor.gen_urls(text)
    
def main():
    with open('messages_to_parse.dat', 'rb') as f:
        # create a list:
        tlds = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')

    urls = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(min(cpu_count(), len(tlds))) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(extract_urls, tld) for tld in tlds]
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            urls.extend(future.result())

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(min(CONNECTIONS, len(urls))) as executor:
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, TIMEOUT): url for 
                         url in urls}
        out = []
        for future in as_completed(future_to_url):
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                data = str(type(exc))
            finally:
                url = future_to_url[future]
                out.append((url, data))
                print(len(out), end="\r")
    print()
    for url, data in out:
        print(url, data)

# Required for multiprocessing on Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instead of obtaining all the URLs first and then performing the HEAD requests for them, the following version attempts to perform the HEAD requests as the URLs are returned by the `URLExtract.gen_urls` method. Performance *might* be slightly improved:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor, \
                               as_completed
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import pickle
import requests
import time
from urlextract import URLExtract

CONNECTIONS = 100
TIMEOUT = 5

def load_url(url, timeout):
    ans = requests.head(url, timeout=timeout)
    return ans.status_code

def extract_urls(text):
    extractor = URLExtract()
    return extractor.gen_urls(text)
    
def main():
    with open('messages_to_parse.dat', 'rb') as f:
        # create a list:
        tlds = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(CONNECTIONS) as thread_executor:
        future_to_url = {}
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(min(cpu_count(), len(tlds))) as process_executor:
            futures = [process_executor.submit(extract_urls, tld) for tld in tlds]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                for url in future.result():
                    future_to_url[thread_executor.submit(load_url, url, TIMEOUT)] = url
        out = []
        for future in as_completed(future_to_url):
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                data = str(type(exc))
            finally:
                url = future_to_url[future]
                out.append((url, data))
                print(len(out), end="\r")
    print()
    for url, data in out:
        print(url, data)

# Required for multiprocessing on Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem?